# Problems with jquery click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery, and despite reading through the guide several times, I can't find the problem.

The following functions are not getting fired when I click on the button:

```
function enable(){
    alert("Enable Working!");
}

function disable(){
    alert("Disable Working!");
}

$("#enable").click(function(){
    $("#enable").hide();
});
$("#disable").click(function(){
    disable();
});
```

And the html page. I don't see any mistakes here either

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>popup</title>
    <style>
        #enable{
            color:green;
            position:relative;
            top:20px;
            }
        #disable{
            color:red;
            position:relative;
            top:25px;
            }
        body{
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body id="popup">
    <input id="enable" type="button" value="Enable">
    <br />
    <input id="disable" type="button" value="Disable">

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>


</body>
<html>
```

What I'd like is for the the `enable` function to run when I click the enable button. I'd like the `disable` function to run when I click the disable button. The alerts are there to test if it's working.

Comment: What is not working? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user2465313, clerify your problem...

Comment: We can't really tell you without knowing what is not working, but should put the query source before your script. This is probably a source of error

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. When I click enable, I'd like the enable function to run. When I click disable, I'd like the disable function to run.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen and what does happen? You don't have your enable function in your enable click event.

Comment: You never invoke the function enable at any point in your script. Try adding it into your script somewhere, probably like this:
`$("#enable").click(function(){
    enable();
    $("#enable").hide();
});
$("#disable").click(function(){
    disable();
});`

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copied the version I was trying to debug. Originally it had the enable function just like the disable has the disable function. They both aren't working

Comment: does it fire any error in the console log??

Comment: If there's a problem with my question, please tell me and I'll fix it. I'm pretty new to stackoverflow and down votes can really hurt me at this point

Comment: I got it working thanks to Theo's answer. Thanks for the help. Sorry it wasn't clear at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the jQuery file first, change the order of your files:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: Weird. I tried this again and it worked. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
function enable(){
    alert("Enable Working!");
}

function disable(){
    alert("Disable Working!");
}

$("#enable").click(enable);

$("#disable").click(disable);
```

And as someone else mentioned, reverse the script includement:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, just change the code inside the #enable click to run the function:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jq7v8/)**

```
$("#enable").click(function(){
    enable();
});
$("#disable").click(function(){
    disable();
});
```

If you want to hide the button, putt it inside the function:

```
function enable(){
    alert("Enable Working!");
    $("#enable").hide();
}
```

Add this to load your code when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code
});
```

The jQuery script file can be loaded from an online source. If you want that the code is `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Load it before your other .js files. If the need jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
function enable(){
    alert("Enable Working!");
}

function disable(){
    alert("Disable Working!");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#enable").click(function(){
        enable();
    });

    $("#disable").click(function(){
        disable();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <title>popup</title>
  <style>
      #enable{
         color:green;
            position:relative;
            top:20px;
            }
        #disable{
           color:red;
          position:relative;
          top:25px;
             }
     body{
             height: 100px;
      }
 </style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 });
function enable(){
   alert("Enable Working!");
}

function disable(){
  alert("Disable Working!");
}

$("#enable").click(function(){

 enable();
});
$("#disable").click(function(){
    disable();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="enable" type="button" value="Enable">
    <br />
    <input id="disable" type="button" value="Disable">
</body>
</html>
```